# Аналог KeyData для Keypress в c#

Tags: c#

Хочу реализовать возможность движения объекта при зажатии клавиши. Ранее использовал form keydown, но получается не очень плавно:

```
private void Form7_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.W)
            pictureBox2.Location = new Point(pictureBox2.Location.X, pictureBox2.Location.Y - 3);
```

Потом решил использовать для реализации keypress и таймер:

```
 private void Form7_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.KeyData == Keys.W)
         pictureBox2.Location = new Point(pictureBox2.Location.X, pictureBox2.Location.Y - 3);
 }
```

Но возникает ошибка: Ошибка 2   "System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs" не содержит определения для "KeyData" и не был найден метод расширения "KeyData", принимающий тип "System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку) 
Ругается на keydata, вопрос, чем заменить keydata в Form_KeyPress?

Comment: Переделал заголовок: поставил метки в конец, хотя можно было и совсем удалить - см. [Следует ли включать метки в заголовок вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3480/213987)

Comment: Вопрос для себя решил, можно закрывать, спасибо.